# PHP read permissions messed up

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx

I'll try to be as clear as possible.
On my server which runs on ubuntu 14 i installed `mutlicraft` (a minecraft control panel).
After uploading the server i noticed that the server wont run. Thats because each server needs hiw own user. In my case i had to change the ownership from `root` user to `mc1`.
Accidentally i typed `chown -R mc1 *` **Yes!** I typed `-R` and took ownership of EVERYTING on the user `mc1`.

**The directory:**

The multicraft server directory: `/home/minecraft/servers/server1`

The multicraft web panel: `/var/www/multicraft`

**The Actual problem**

After doing this the panel is not accessible. Why? Because of this:

```
2014/10/10 16:19:07 [error] 1368#0: *15 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:            Uncaught exception 'CException' with message 'Application runtime path             "/var/www/multicraft/protected/runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by  the Web server process.' in /var/www/multicraft/protected/yii/base/CApplication.php:271
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/multicraft/protected/yii/base/CApplication.php(258): CApplication-   >setRuntimePath('/var/www/multic...')
#1 /var/www/multicraft/protected/yii/base/CStatePersister.php(67): CApplication->getRuntimePath()
#2 /var/www/multicraft/protected/yii/base/CModule.php(388): CStatePersister->init() 
#3 /var/www/multicraft/protected/yii/base/CApplication.php(458): CModule->getComponent('statePersister')
#4 /var/www/multicraft/protected/yii/base/CApplication.php(651): CApplication->getStatePersister()
#5 /var/www/multicraft/protected/yii/base/CApplication.php(592): CApplication->loadGlobalState()
#6 /var/www/multicraft/protected/yii/base/CSecurityManager.php(101): CApplication->getGlobalState('Yii.CSecurityMa" while reading response header from upstream, client: 85.74.3.56, server: localhost, request: "GET /multicraft/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "37.59.112.131"
```

After doing this i hit `chown -R mc1 *` in order to reverse the action and it worked except from the `www`

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From what you pasted it seems the problem is that the web server user has no write permission in this folder '/var/www/multicraft/protected/runtime'

This is probably related to your ownership change.
You can keep the user you want, but be sure your webserver user can write the directory. You can get this working using groups (create a group with your user, the minecraft user and the webserver use and gave this group write permission on the www folder, doing a chown mc1:group /var/www/) or you can set 777 permission to the webpanel folder (not safe if your machine have other than you as regular user)

I hope I've not misunderstood your question.